# jQuery, new instance of custom object

Tags: jquery, object

I'm creating some kind of widget and I need some kind of

```
widget = widget || {};
widget = (function() {
    var p = 'some value';

    function config(){
        //some config actions
    }
})();

var o1 = widget.config(); // do this one return an object\instance?
var o2 = widget.config(); // and this one return another instance or same as in o1 ?
```

Where `o1 != o2` (as instances), so they have different properties values. And when I change one, another one should not be changed.

```
o1.p = 'some';
o2.p = 'another';
// so should be o1.p != o2.p
```

Same way as php or other OOP language do.

How can i do this using jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried the jQuery Widget Factory? https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/

Comment: @Barmar nice one, will read it later, but now I need to quick fix existing code, so total refactor for me is bad solution. All I need it to get new instances...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create jQuery widgets with the Widget Factory. This is simple enough.
Of course, there are quite a few methods you can implement ( e.g. `_destroy`, `_setOption` and `_create`).

[More Information](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/)

```js
$(function() {

  $.widget("ns.widget", { // "ns" is your namespace; "widget" can be anything
    // induvidually stored values (with defaults)
    options: {
      p: "some value"
    },

    // the constructor
    _create: function() {
      this.element.text(this.options.p);
    }
  });

  // create a few
  $("#o1").widget({p: "some"})
  $("#o2").widget({p: "other"})
  $("#o3").widget()

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="o1"></div>
<div id="o2"></div>
<div id="o3"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

now the code you've posted looks like plain JavaScript. To create objects like this you need the `new` keyword

```
function Widget(p) { // constructor
  this.p = p || "some value"
}
Widget.prototype = { // more functions
  "print": function() {
    console.log(this.p)
  }
}

// create either like this
var o1 = new Widget('some')
// or
var o2 = new Widget()
o2.p = 'another'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Javascript OOP:

```
function widget() {
    var p = 'some_value';
    this.config = function() {
        // some config action
    };
}

var o1 = new widget();
o1.config();
var o2 = new widget();
o2.config();
```

If `config()` doesn't use `p`, you could just define it once:

```
widget.prototype.config = function() {
    // some config action
};
```